# Reference middleman config property dynamically based on current page

Tags: ruby, json, erb, middleman

I have a JSON data file in my Middleman project that has an object with info about 5 sections of a a site where we are building prototypes for a new project. Here is part of that file:

```
"industries": {
  "Insulation": {
    "url": "insulation",
    "color": "#B48126"
  },
  "Roofing": {
    "url": "roofing",
    "color": "#52bd4a"
  }, ...
```

I'd like to pull attributes from that object based on the current page.

For instance, if I'm on page in the Insulation section, I'd like grab the highlight color for insulation from that file and use it as part of the prototype, so that we can try different colors for the client.

At the top of each .erb template, I could very easily put this page data variable to denote the industry:

```
;;;
"product": "Commerical Insulation",
"division": "insulation"
;;;
```

and then further down the template, use things like this:

```
  <img  class="img-responsive center-block" 
        src="<%= lorem.image('1140x100', 
              :text => current_page.data.product + ' image', 
              :color => data.lists.industries.{current_page.data.division}.color) %>" />
```

I know `{current_page.data.division}` is not right (throws a *syntax error, unexpected tLBRACE*).

I'm new to Ruby and ERB, so if there is a better way to approach this, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `data.lists.industries[current_page.data.division].color`?

Comment: His approach is a normal construct used in middleman applications and he has problems mixing the two data sources within the `img` tag (throws a syntax error). I was aiming to help him with that concrete error. What's wrong about that?

Comment: @Pranav,Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had finally come across this syntax and found that it worked, but I appreciate the confirmation that this is a good way to do it.

Comment: Nothing wrong in the answer ,if it helps and of-course it helped. but the way its posted it seems you are asking rather than answering... :)